# How can I capture real-time audio in a browser on the client-side?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, webrtc

I'm interested in capturing audio from Google Meet/Zoom/Microsoft Teams/etc calls and performing real-time transcription using an API within my browser extension app. While I'm aware of WebRTC as a potential solution, I'm still don't understand how to implement it. Could someone provide guidance on how to utilize WebRTC for this purpose or something similar.

Please, bear with me and thanks in advance!!

Comment: Doesn’t Google Meet have a transcription feature built in?

Comment: Sure, but I want to learn how to do that on my own and make an extension that does that realtime as well. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Internet search the terms "Google Meet API" to find the official docs (if any), then from there see if there are any commands that support this (capturing audio). That is, conduct research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remap system audio to an input device then successively call `webkitSpeechRecognition()`, which send captured microphone to remote Google servers and sends back the transcription.

On Chrome, there is a way to get the direct URL (and Google API key) used to send the local microphone recording to by logging all network requests, calling `webkitSpeechRecognition()` and observing the URL in the net log. Thereafter you can send the audio, including any real-time captured streams, directly to Google's speech recognition server used for Chrome's implementation of Web Speech API.

Note, it is now, after 5 years of not being able to, capture entire system audio on Chrome using Web API's, see https://gist.github.com/guest271314/baaa0b8d4b034ff4e9352af4f2bbf42c.

Comment: Again… off-topic question. Seems odd for someone with such extreme reputation to be fielding these questions.

Comment: I'm trying to share the knowledge I have. You are trying to withhold the knowledge you have.